# conduct Wilcoxon-test and t-test by using for loop for all columns at once

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns. The first column contains categories such as "System 1", "System 2", and the second column has numbers that represent the 0's and 1's. Please see below :

For example:

| SYSTEM | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| System 1 | 0 | 1 |
| System 1 | 1 | 0 |
| System 2 | 1 | 1 |
| System 2 | 0 | 0 |
| System 2 | 1 | 1 |

How to write R code to run a paired Wilcoxon test for multiple columns from 1 to 100 using a for loop or other recommended solutions.

Here is my data

```
x<-"SYSTEM  Q1  Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
S1  0   1    0   0  0   
S1  1   0    1   1  1
S2  1   1    1   1  1     
S2  0   0    1   1   0
S2  1   1   0    0  0"
mydata <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

n <- 1e4
df2 <- data.frame(
  SYSTEM = sample(mydata$SYSTEM, n, TRUE),
  Q1 = sample(mydata$Q1, n, TRUE),
  Q2 = sample(mydata$Q2, n, TRUE), 
  Q3 = sample(mydata$Q3, n, TRUE),
  Q4 = sample(mydata$Q4, n, TRUE),
  Q5 = sample(mydata$Q5, n, TRUE)
)
```

Comment: Are you also going to control for the multiple comparisons problem?

Comment: No, I'm only interested in comparing them within subjects such as system 1 vs. system 2 for each question. if it's just a function I would like to see that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `fo`rmula and `update` in each iteration.

```
fo <- x ~ SYSTEM

t(sapply(names(df2[-1]), \(x) {
  wt <- wilcox.test(update(fo, paste(x, '~ .')), df2, paired=TRUE)[c('statistic', 'p.value')]
  tt <- t.test(update(fo, paste(x, '~ .')), df2, paired=TRUE)[c('statistic', 'p.value')]
  unlist(c(w=wt, t=tt))
}))
#    w.statistic.V w.p.value t.statistic.t t.p.value
# Q1       1545406 0.2021674    -1.2754967 0.2021928
# Q2       1592619 0.6752919     0.4188777 0.6753235
# Q3       1544422 0.8408638     0.2007856 0.8408744
# Q4       1572435 0.4583192     0.7416000 0.4583646
# Q5       1634352 0.2405299     1.1737235 0.2405617
```

Notice that your example data is flawed; S1 and S2 in SYSTEM need to be of equal size to run a paired test. Look into `str(wilcox.test(.))` and `str(t.test(.))` of a single run in case you want to include more stuff in `c('statistic', 'p.value')]`. Also consider *@IRTFM*'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760217/conduct-wilcoxon-test-and-t-test-by-using-for-loop-for-all-columns-at-once/73760903#comment130246913_73760217) to take multiple comparisons into account, such as Bonferroni or FDR.

---

*Data:*

```
m <- 1e4; n <- 5
set.seed(42)
df2 <- data.frame(SYSTEM=rep(c('S1', 'S2'), each=n/2), matrix(sample(0:1, m*n, replace=TRUE), m, n))
names(df2)[-1] <- paste0('Q', 1:n)
```

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf. I got an error. Please see below

Comment: @catcat Use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` or update your R ;)

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf. The works fine. However, I can't see the result in the same format as I expected on my question. I don't know which one is system 1 or system 2 . It gives me all results together. I also got this message :Warning: requested conf.level not achievable . What is this mean ? .Please see my question again in the last part. Thanks again.

Comment: @catcat I've seen your expected format, it makes no sense to me, though: A [Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test](https://data.library.virginia.edu/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test/) comparing system 1 and system 2 gives exactly one W statistic and one p value for me? This applies similarly to a t-test. No idea where your warning comes from. Could you provide: 1. One _single_ `wilcox.test` and 2. one _single_ `t.test` of how you do this with say column Q1?

Comment: thank you for your comment, and I updated the question to address your request.

Comment: @catcat In the tests there is always one w or t statistic and one p-value. So, really not sure what the two-row format should show.

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf. The format looks good now. I just want to do this in function  as I sent this way new to me and I want to learn how to do it , so the input would be something like (Q1) then the function takes all questions then call it in wilcox.test(system1$q1, system2$q1) -----esult will be " Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction" for each question.  My example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766286/how-to-use-test-wilcox-test-to-print-each-column-in-function-at-once.